# Sitecore set Default Rich Text Editor for Specific Site

Tags: sitecore

If we want to change the default Rich Text Editor for sitecore website, we got below option to change.

```
<setting name="HtmlEditor.DefaultProfile" value="/sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text Default" />
```

I have three websites in my sitecore instance. Is there any way that I can specify different default RTE to each websites. I am on Sitecore 6.5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not readily available out of the box, no. You would need to go to your Rich Text fields and specify the editor to be used per-field; and if the fields are not shared on templates across sites - that would be it. But it is unlikely; normally many templates would be shared and another solution made up to solve this requirement.